# In a VBA Userform, which event is triggered when exiting a filed

Tags: vba, userform

I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus (64 bit) on a Windows 10 (64 bit) platform.  I have a subroutine that is processed when I make a change to a Userform field called `MyDate`.  It's called `Private Sub MyDate_AfterUpdate()`.  It's the second field on a form.  It works fine as long as the contents of the `MyDate` field are edited.  However, if the user doesn't need to update the contents of the `MyDate` field because they accept the default of the field and just presses the tab key past that second field, I'd still like the subroutine to be executed.  What event can I use to activate code when I simply tab through the field and don't necessarily edit the contents?  Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the top of the code panes, you'll notice two dropdowns. The left one contains all interfaces and event providers you can implement in that class (a `UserForm` is a class).

[image: left dropdown listing (General), UserForm and TextBox1 items]

Select your `MyDate` control from that dropdown; the right-side dropdown is now listing every event you could handle for this `MyDate` control:

[image: right dropdown listing TextBox1 events]

In this particular case, the `Exit` event seems a good candidate:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'make Cancel.Value = True to prevent exiting the control.
    '...ideally... make that conditional...
End Sub
```

By consistently using these dropdowns to let the VBE generate event handler procedures for you (instead of typing them up from memory), you avoid getting it wrong... and getting an event handler signature wrong can do anything from literally nothing at all, to compile errors if you're lucky, or weird and hard-to-diagnose behavior if you're less lucky.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mathieu.  That solved the problem.  I appreciate your help.